# Encrypt or secure files in sd-card so that those files can only be used/access by my android application

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, sd-card

I have requirements, i am not very sure how to post it but what i want to do is to secure my sdcard files in such a way

- Those files can only be read by my android application.
- No one can copy or cut those files from sd-card or if he can those files should not be accessible to them.

Files include (Videos , photos ).

Comment: It seems like you can't, if it is in sd-card. The common solution of your requirement is encode your files in your own format so that you are the only one can decode them.

Comment: You are saying about android encryption or decryption ? or decrypt the files from my application?

Comment: Basiclly, yes,  but I think videos and photos actually is not appropriate for content encoding , maybe change the description of file header and change it back before you read it. But if you are talking about high level security issue, then you should hire an expert.